# Problem retrieving updated state value in my component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

I Have a component (simple) and a reducer to modify value in my state.
I increment my value in my state, but when I want to display this value updated in my component, it's not updated with the new state value.

I don't know if my usedispatch is incorrect.
In my dev tools I see my state updated and incremented, but my page don't change...

Here is my reducer:

```
    import { data } from "jquery";
    
    export const INCREMENT_COUNTER = "INCREMENT_COUNTER";
    export const DECREMENT_COUNTER = "DECREMENT_COUNTER";
    
    export function increment(amount) {
        console.log('-------------------amount', amount);
        return {
            type: INCREMENT_COUNTER,
            payload: amount
        }
    }
    
    export function decrement(amount) {
        return {
            type: DECREMENT_COUNTER,
            payload: amount,
        };
    }
    
    
    const initialState = {
        data: 42,
    }
    
    
    export default function testReducer(state = initialState, {type, payload}) {
        Object.assign(state.data, data);
        switch (type) {
            case INCREMENT_COUNTER:
                console.log('increment reducer', {...state});
                return {
                    ...state,
                    ...state.data,
                    data:  state.data + payload,
    
                };
            case DECREMENT_COUNTER:
                console.log('decrement reducer');
                return {
                    //...state,
                    data: state.data - payload,
                };
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }
```

and there is my component :

```
    import React, {useCallback, useEffect} from "react"
    import { useStore } from "react-redux";
    import {useDispatch, useSelector} from "react-redux"
    import {decrement, increment} from "./testReducer.js"
    
    export default function Sandbox() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const data = useSelector((state) => state.test);

    const store= useStore();
    const toto = store.getState().test.data;

    console.log('------------ttititi--------', store.getState().test.data);

    const inc = useCallback(() => {
        console.log('-----------inc', data);
        console.log('-----------inc2', toto);    
        dispatch(increment(2))

        }, [dispatch, data, toto]
    );

    const dec = useCallback(() => {
        dispatch(decrement(2))
    }, [dispatch, data]);
    return (
        <>
        {toto.test?.data}
            <h1>Testin2g</h1>
            <h3>The data is: {data.data} --  {toto}</h3>
            <button onClick={inc} content="increment" color="green">increment</button>
            <button onClick={dec} content="decrement" color="red">decrement</button>
        </>
    )
}
```

This is how I do in my rootReducer:

```
     import {combineReducers} from 'redux'
     import testReducer from "../sandbox/testReducer.js";
     import authReducer from "../modules/auth/authReducer";
     import businessesReducer from "../modules/business/businessesReducer";
     // import eventReducer from '../../features/events/eventReducer'

     const rootReducer = combineReducers({
         test: testReducer,
         auth: authReducer,
         businesses: businessesReducer,
         // event: eventReducer
     })

     export default rootReducer;
```

configureStore.js file :

```
import {applyMiddleware, compose, createStore} from "redux"
import rootReducer from "./rootReducer"
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

export function configureStore() {
    const composeEnchancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
    return createStore(rootReducer, composeEnchancer(applyMiddleware(thunk)))
}
```

Comment: How are you configuring your redux store? Are you selecting the correct state?

Comment: `const data = useSelector((state) => state.test);` have you logged this ? it might be `const data = useSelector((state) => state.testReducer.test); ??` the name of your testReducer while importing it in `combinReducer()` ?

Comment: I juste updated my post to answer you.

Comment: Copy/pasted your code into a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/problem-retrieving-updated-state-value-in-my-component-1tzrs) and it seems to run without issue, I see increment/decrement working.

Comment: @DrewReese not a good news for me... :)
Is there a file which can cause my problem?

I update my post with the configureStore if you want to look at it...

Comment: I wouldn't think so. I forgot to mention what stuck out to me was the `import { data } from "jquery";` and `Object.assign(state.data, data);` in the reducer code. I didn't import `data` and commented out the `Object.assign` line in my linked CSB. What is the purpose of these in your code?

Comment: Object.assign() it was for a test, the dta, it's not me who did his...
I deleted this 2 lines, but when I click on of the 2 buttons in my sandbox page, the part "the data is { data }" not changing with my new value....

I really don't understand....

Comment: Did you get this figured out or do you still have the issue with `data` not updating? Can you share your codesandbox page for use to inspect and debug live?

Comment: Finally, there was a problem with an extenal library we used for a DataGrid and the state was broken du to that.
Weird....
Thank you for your help.